# jQuery Pajinate - everything is showing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, jquery-pagination

I'm using the Pajinate plugin: https://github.com/wesnolte/Pajinate

When I first load a page all the divs that are to be paged show. If I click to the second page I only see 2 divs (I will be using 20 per page, but reduced to 2 for testing) as I should. If I then click back to the first page I only see 2. I can't figure out why the divs after the first 2 aren't being hidden.

My initial call is:

```
$('#paging_container').pajinate({
    items_per_page : 2,
    num_page_links_to_display : 6,
    abort_on_small_lists: true,
    item_container_id : '.paging_content',
    nav_panel_id : '.page_navigation'
});
```

The page links are being limited to 6 and the info text shows "Showing 1-2 of 57 results" which is correct.

Any suggestions of where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to add the page: http://www.heartofbusiness.com/alumni-community-list/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Just clipped out some code and finally it looks like:

```
$('#paging_container').paginate({
  items_per_page : 2,
  num_page_links_to_display : 6,
  abort_on_small_lists: true
});
```

I personally using this pagination and it works for me.

Comment: This should be .pajinate(), not .paginate(). Otherwise works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring the start page to see if it makes any difference/

From the documentation:

```
start_page : The page number you'd like to display first [default = 0]
```

Try setting it :

```
$('#paging_container').pajinate({
  items_per_page : 2,
  num_page_links_to_display : 6,
  abort_on_small_lists: true,
  item_container_id : '.paging_content',
  nav_panel_id : '.page_navigation',
  start_page: 0 //here's our addition
});
```

Comment: No change. I did try changing it to start on page 2 and while the highlighted page in the nav_panel changed to 3 all 57 divs still showed.

Comment: This call is made at the end of the scripts.js file which loads at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Set style attribute to value "`display:none;`" for all paginated items (excluding the items for page 0). It'll force browser to hide them while JavaScript is been loaded.